# ES6: Object Manipulation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The requirement is that I have to group by the key 'taxGrp'. 'taxtGrp' should contain 'name' and 'income'. 'income' is nothing but the combined income of the group
If taxGrp is NON_TAX' then name = 'members' and income = 1000 (as per below sample data)
If taxGrp is not 'NON_TAX' then name = name of the person whose 'relation' is 'CHILD' in that group and income's value is the combined income of that group.
I'm unable to. get the desired output.

```
var grp = [
{
    taxGrp: 'NON_TAX',
  name: 'Mary Zelle',
  relation: 'APPLICANT',
  income:  '500'
},
{
  taxGrp: 'NON_TAX',
  name: 'Jack Zelle',
  relation: 'SPOUSE',
  income:  '500'
},
{
    taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_1',
  name: 'Victor Zele',
  relation: 'CHILD',
  income: 200
},
{
    taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_1',
  name: 'Rosey Zele',
  relation: 'DEPENDANT',
  income: 100

},
{
    taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_2',
  name: 'Derk Zele',
  relation: 'CHILD',
  income: 300
},
{
    taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_2',
  name: 'Marc Zele',
  relation: 'DEPENDANT',
  income: null
}
];
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
[
'NON_TAX': {
   name: 'members'
   income:  1000
},
'TAX_GRP_1': {
   name: 'Victor Zele',
   income:  400
},
'TAX_GRP_2': {
   name: 'Derk Zele',
   income:  300
}
]
```

```js
var grp = [
{
    taxGrp: 'NON_TAX',
  name: 'Mary Beth',
  relation: 'PARENT'
},
{
    taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_1',
  name: 'Victor Zele',
  relation: 'CHILD'
},
{
    taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_1',
  name: 'Rosey Zele',
  relation: 'DEPENDANT'
},
{
    taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_2',
  name: 'Derk Zele',
  relation: 'CHILD'
},
{
    taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_2',
  name: 'Marc Zele',
  relation: 'DEPENDANT'
}
];

var memberObj = grp.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val.taxGrp] = {
    name: val.name
  };
  return acc
}, {});

console.log('memberObj >>', memberObj);
```

Comment: Why is this question. given a -ve vote?

Comment: The expected output isn't valid JS.

Comment: If you expect the output to include `income:  ...` why aren't you including input in the value you assign in the reducer function?

Comment: @Quentin -- unable to add income.

Comment: What's stopping you? It's just a property of `val` like `name`.

Comment: Try running my snippet now. I've added the income. see the output

Comment: That doesn't tell me what is preventing you from including the valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249887/discussion-between-dragonfly-and-quentin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somme issues:

- The input has a mixed type for `income`: sometimes it is a string, sometimes a number. This should be harmonised.
- Your code has no attempt to access `income`, let be that the output would contain anything that relates to it
- The output format is not valid. Array literal notation does not allow named properties like 'NON_TAX'. I'll assume you actually didn't want an array, but a plain object
- There is no attempt in your code to give a special role to objects that have a `relation` that is "CHILD". You should only set the `name` property when that is true or the `taxGrp` is "NON_TAX"

Here is your `reduce` callback adapted with the above points in mind:

```js
var grp = [
{taxGrp: 'NON_TAX',name: 'Mary Zelle',relation: 'APPLICANT',income:  500},
{taxGrp: 'NON_TAX',name: 'Jack Zelle',relation: 'SPOUSE',income:  500},
{taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_1',name: 'Victor Zele',relation: 'CHILD',income: 200},
{taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_1',name: 'Rosey Zele',relation: 'DEPENDANT',income: 100},
{taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_2',name: 'Derk Zele',relation: 'CHILD',income: 300},
{taxGrp: 'TAX_GRP_2',name: 'Marc Zele',relation: 'DEPENDANT',income: null}];

var memberObj = grp.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val.taxGrp] ??= { income: 0 };
  if (val.taxGrp === "NON_TAX" || val.relation == "CHILD") {
    acc[val.taxGrp].name = val.taxGrp === "NON_TAX" ? "members" : val.name;
  }
  acc[val.taxGrp].income += +val.income;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log('memberObj >>', memberObj);
```

Comment: can you kindly explain acc[val.taxGrp] ??= { income: 0 }; Why do we have too do this?

Comment: This is a [nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment), i.e. when `acc[val.taxGrp]` doesn't exist yet, it is created with `{ income: 0 }` as object value. In a later statement that 0 will be updated.